# How to check if a string in an array contains any special characters?

Tags: typescript

I want to check if any of a string in an array contains any special character. I have tried RegExp, test, contains & includes but nothing gives me an expected result. For all the string it returns false.

```
let prodList: string[] = ['H&W', 'Tony$Talk', 'GP', '(Test*)'];
specialCharactersList = '/[!@#$%^&*()+\\-=[]{};':\"|,.<>/?`~';
for(var i = 0; i < prodList.length ; i++)
{
console.log(prodList[i].includes(specialCharactersList));
console.log(prodList[i].contains(specialCharactersList));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that you actually want to check for a string containing special characters, since you will not be able to list all. You probably want to test for **valid** characters and see if the string matches your expectation.

The following RegEx matches all letters, digits, underscores and whitespaces and checks if the given string does only contain these characters.

```
let prodList: string[] = ['H&W', 'Tony$Talk', 'GP', '(Test*)'];
let specialCharactersList = /^[\w\s]*$/;
for(var i = 0; i < prodList.length ; i++)
{
  
console.log(specialCharactersList.test(prodList[i]));
}
```

will result in

```
false
false
true
false
```

Comment: Is it possible to include additional special characters in the white list. I want to allow _ ( )

Comment: `_` is included in `\w`. If you want to allow parantheses you can add them to your list of allowed characters like `\w\s\(\)`

Comment: Thanks, it is working.. I've tried using {var regex2 = new RegExp('[ A-Za-z0-9_/& ]');} but it is not working. Do you have any idea why it is not working when we use RegExp?

Comment: Well, probably because in your implementation you only test if one of the characters mentioned is included in your string, and not if the whole string only consists of these characters. To do this you have to prefix with `^` and postfix with `$`. Also you have to repeat the allowed characters using `*` after your group. Like `new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9_/&]*$');`

Comment: If my answer did help you, please mark it as accepted and close the question if possible.